# Predict values from multivariate linear model

Tags: r, statistics, regression, predict

I need help predicting a value from new data, from a multivariate lm model.

```
project_model <- lm(project_data$Log.Odds.Ratio ~ project_data$Complexity.Level + project_data$Product.Type + project_data$Plant.Normalized.Hours + project_data$Norm.Sq.Ft)
```

(Four predictors)

I want to predict the Log.Odds.Ratio from a new set of data. (Same column names)

```
new_data <- data.frame(Complexity.Level = 3,Product.Type = "End",Plant.Normalized.Hours = 1.5 ,Norm.Sq.Ft = -0.6458333)
new_data[1,1] <- factor(new_data[1,1])
predict(project_model,new_data,interval='confidence')
```

However, I get this error

```
Warning message:
'newdata' had 1 row but variables found have 260 rows
```

Along with the 260 predicted values from the data set I used to fit the model, but none are from the new data I have.

I have done

mtcars <- mtcars
mtcars$cyl <- factor(mtcars$cyl)

```
mtcars.lm <- lm(mpg ~ hp + cyl + disp + vs, data = mtcars)

# hp = 110
# cyl = 6
# disp = 200
# vs = 1

new_data <- data.frame(hp = 110, cyl = 6, disp = 200, vs = 1)
new_data$cyl <- factor(new_data$cyl)

predict(mtcars.lm,new_data,interval = 'confidence')
```

And it works! I don't know what is the difference, but for some reason I can't get it to work with my actual data.

Comment: The difference seems fairly obvious. Putting columns in formulas with the dataset name like `project_data$Log.Odds.Ratio` is a strategy for failure. Try using `project_model <- lm(Log.Odds.Ratio ~Complexity.Level +Product.Type +Plant.Normalized.Hours +Norm.Sq.Ft, data=project_data)`. Then a 'newdata' argument will have more chance for success.

Comment: Lol thank you so much! I'll definitely be more diligent for this in the future.